The clumsiest instrument in a symphonic orchestra
Is it possible to say which one of the musical instruments listed below is the most 'clumsy' or is it too subjective a question?
By 'clumsy,' I mean at least the following two characteristics: 1) the instrument is the hardest to start a sound, i.e. has the slowest attack; 2) it is the hardest to play fast passages;
If the question is really too subjective and, thus, impossible to answer objectively, then consider only the first characteristic. In other words, the question then is about the instrument with the slowest sound attack, which I suspect must be an instrument from the brass family.
e image is taken from this Wiki article: Range_(music)


I think it's too subjective a question - an accomplished player on any will be able to play that instrument really well, so comparison is difficult to impossible.

I'm not sure whether there is an answer to this question; however, reading up on the various disadvantages and issues with individual instruments is enormously entertaining. See e.g. W. Piston, Orchestration.

@Tim I challenge you to find a performance of Flight of the Bumblebee on tuba and tell with a straight face that it does not have any clumsy or comical elements to it

@ojs - I thought bumble bee was comical anyway..!

I won’t take a crack at answering this but I would say that your answer would probably lie in the realm of extreme lower pitched instruments and the sub category of wind and brass because of the amount of air required and the sizes of the instruments.

@JohnBelzaguy - That's an interesting insight. Thank you.

@brilliant All that being said, many instruments, even ones that are difficult to play can be played at virtuosic levels by some musicians.

Maybe this question would make more sense if it were “which instruments are hardest to learn to play with agility?” The trombone definitely has agility limitations in its lower range because some adjacent notes require moving the slide from one end to the other very quickly and precisely. Then again, going from the lowest to highest string on a strings family instrument can be very difficult.

The issue is further complicated by the fact that most instruments have a range, and might respond differently at different points in it. That might not even be linear; which string is used, or the placement of the instrument's fundamental frequency, etc might cause spikes and valleys in some graph of "responsiveness." On top of that, musical "topography" might matter; maybe you can move quickly in a scalar motion but not over broad leaps—or maybe the opposite; you can roll a bow more quickly over multiple strings than you can move your left hand.

I’m voting to close this question but not calling it "opinion-based"; rather, my reason is that it's impossible to answer with any reasonable precision, only to make large generalizations (double bass, tuba, and alphorn are less agile than piccolo, violin, and xylophone).

@AndyBonner - "it's impossible to answer with any reasonable precision" -- Well, if you stick only to the characteristic of the sound attack speed, then I think the precision is possible.


the instrument with the slowest sound attack

This is definitely the tam-tam. They have to be “warmed up” by playing them very quietly for a few beats before the actual first note in the music. Even when warmed up, it can take half a second or so for a larger tam-tam to reach its peak loudness after being played.

it is the hardest to play fast passages

The trombone in its lowest register has the complication that some note changes require widely separated slide positions. It’s hard to position the slide accurately when you’re only moving from position 2 to 3, for example. Going from 1 to 7 and back very quickly and accurately is extremely challenging. Valved brass instruments (like horns, tubas, and euphoniums, all of which are less agile than woodwinds) are more agile.
In the upper registers there are multiple slide position options for each note, so you don’t have to move the slide as far. Still, quick accuracy is harder than with valves, and you still have to have solid double- or triple-tonguing ability and great intonation and audiation of destination pitches (common to all brass).
Honorable mentions for a couple instruments that I would not describe as “symphonic”: Bowed vibraphone is quite “clumsy” and starting the first notes on highland bagpipes is very slow compared with other instruments.

Very interesting! Thank you. I didn't even know anything about bowed vibraphones before your answer.

@brilliant One thing I calculated thinking about this was that there could be a 5-15 ms delay in onset of the first full sound of a low brass instrument (horn, trombone, euphonium, or tuba). That amount of time wouldn't be consciously noticed by the vast majority of listeners, but can be musically significant, at least for the player. Still, that delay is less than the amount of time it takes for that same sound to cross the stage once it has emerged from the bell (20-100 ms). Woodwind and string instruments would not have this delay.

Yes, once I entered measures containing four beats for brass and winds into my music editor to be played simultaneously. I remember my initial puzzlement when the delay of the brass from the winds was obvious and repeated every beat during playback. Now I understand the reason. However, I wonder if that delay would somehow be smoothed out by the players in a real-life situation.

@brilliant Absolutely. All players learn what they have to do with their instruments to make the resulting ensemble sound correct. For low brass, it usually means starting notes slightly early.

Got it. Thank you!

The stock answers would, I suppose, be tuba or contra-bassoon.
But before you are tempted to let that information influence you too much, watch this!  I'd even argue that, apart from the agility, it's a more accurate impression of the insect than any other instrument could deliver!




This puts paid to most theories..! +1.

Definitely not contra. Woodwinds have keys that let them make wide leaps and fast runs much more easily than brass. I think tuba is more agile than bass trombone. The slide really slows things down in ways that valves don’t. Maybe my view isn’t fair because I’ve seen a virtuoso tuba performance that was extremely agile.

I found a couple impressive trombone renditions of “Bumblebee” and neither was as clean as the tuba one you found.
